# Converting code from using .bind(this) to arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I have recently been informed that it is not good to use bind(this) in the render function because it creates brand new functions every time. I am therefore moving towards using arrow functions as you see below in the two `<button>` elements.

The question I have is about the map function. It is also using .bind(this). Is there a way to convert this to an ES6/7 format?

```
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>this.changeDisplayType("images")}>Images</button>
        <button onClick={()=>this.changeDisplayType("audio")}>Audio</button>
        {
            resources.map(function(resource) {
                return (
                    <div key={resource.id}>
                        <div style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{resource.name}</div>
                        <div>({resource.info})</div>
                    </div>
                )
            }.bind(this))
        }


    </div>
)
```

I also just realized that I can remove the .bind(this) completely and my code still works. Therefore I am also wondering what difference it makes if its there or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert this to an ES6/7 format?

Yes, you can write it like this by using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
resources.map(resource => {
    return (
        <div key={resource.id}>
            <div style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{resource.name}</div>
            <div>({resource.info})</div>
        </div>
    )
})
```

> I can remove the .bind(this) completely and my code still works WHY?

Because you are not using `this` keyword in map body, means if you try to access any class property or method without binding the callback method, it will throw error.

**Try this:** remove binding and try to access the state value inside map body, it will throw error.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct, thank you. I was copying another module of mine and was just using a smaller subset that doesn't use the word this. So, just to make sure I am understanding everything fully: when using `this` within the map body, the arrow function is more efficient because the function will not be recreated. However, if I do not use the word `this` in the map body, then I can just leave off `.bind(this)` and both approaches will be nearly as efficient as each other?

Comment: if you are not using `this` in map body then you can leave this part `.bind(this)` and arrow function,  regarding re-creation of function as per my knowledge arrow function will create new function at each re-rendering, if you want to avoid this then write it like this: `resources.map(this._functionName)` and bind this method in the constructor now only one reference will be there.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer and further explanation. It looks like I must have misunderstood something I was reading about arrow functions.

Comment: check this doc statement about `onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}` *The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the component renders.* [**Link**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) (last para of the page)